# How to send text from Activity to WallpaperService class

Tags: android, android-intent, live-wallpaper

I want to send text from MainActivity to WallpaperService class to draw Text.

Main Activity class-->

```
Intent in = new Intent();


    in.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER);
                in.putExtra("name", "sample text");
                startActivity(in);
```

WallpaperService class -->

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String value = bundle.getString("key");
```

But the getIntent() method is not available in WallpaperService class.

Comment: kindly look here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/wallpaper/WallpaperService.html

Answer (score -1):

1) Use the Bundle from the Intent:
`Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
Bundle extras = mIntent.getExtras();
extras.putString(key, value)`

**New Context (can be Activity/Service etc)**

```
 Intent myIntent = getIntent(); // this getter is just for example purpose, can differ
if (myIntent !=null && myIntent.getExtras()!=null)
     String value = myIntent.getExtras().getString(key);
}
```

Comment: Where its is showing null pointer error can you post some code so that can get a better idea for the same

Comment: The below code is in Main Activity class and showing null pointer exception in last line.                                         Intent mIntent = new Intent(SetWallpaperActivity.this, LiveWallpaperService.class);
   Bundle extras = mIntent.getExtras();
   extras.putString("name", "sample");